# Getting error on JSON validation

Tags: json

Getting like

Parse error on line 2:
[    {        id: 3306331,
--------------^
Expecting 'STRING', '}' (pro.jsonlint.com).

any help on this?

```
[{ id : 3306331, values : ['012', '416', '003'], labels : ['12', 'CARIBBEAN SEA', 'MEDIUM - $49.99 - Limited Stock']}, { id : 3306340, values : ['008', '416', '003'], labels : ['8', 'CARIBBEAN SEA', 'MEDIUM - $49.99 - Limited Stock']}, { id : 3053686, values : ['008', '044', '003'], labels : ['8', 'NAVY', 'MEDIUM - $49.99 - Limited Stock']}, { id : 3053680, values : ['008', '609', '003'], labels : ['8', 'RAYA LILAC SACHET', 'MEDIUM - $34.88 - Limited Stock']}, { id : 3714924, values : ['008', '120', '003'], labels : ['8', 'SWEDISH BLUE', 'MEDIUM - $34.88 - Limited Stock']}, { id : 3306329, values : ['009', '416', '003'], labels : ['9', 'CARIBBEAN SEA', 'MEDIUM - $49.99 - Limited Stock']}, { id : 3053687, values : ['009', '044', '003'], labels : ['9', 'NAVY', 'MEDIUM - $49.99 - Limited Stock']}, { id : 3053681, values : ['009', '609', '003'], labels : ['9', 'RAYA LILAC SACHET', 'MEDIUM - $34.88 - Limited Stock']}, { id : 3714925, values : ['009', '120', '003'], labels : ['9', 'SWEDISH BLUE', 'MEDIUM - $34.88 - Limited Stock']}, { id : 3306339, values : ['010', '416', '003'], labels : ['10', 'CARIBBEAN SEA', 'MEDIUM - $49.99 - Limited Stock']}, { id : 3053682, values : ['010', '609', '003'], labels : ['10', 'RAYA LILAC SACHET', 'MEDIUM - $34.88 - Limited Stock']}, { id : 3714926, values : ['010', '120', '003'], labels : ['10', 'SWEDISH BLUE', 'MEDIUM - $34.88 - In Stock']}, { id : 3306330, values : ['011', '416', '003'], labels : ['11', 'CARIBBEAN SEA', 'MEDIUM - $49.99 - Limited Stock']}, { id : 3053689, values : ['011', '044', '003'], labels : ['11', 'NAVY', 'MEDIUM - $49.99 - Limited Stock']}, { id : 3053683, values : ['011', '609', '003'], labels : ['11', 'RAYA LILAC SACHET', 'MEDIUM - $34.88 - Limited Stock']}, { id : 3714927, values : ['011', '120', '003'], labels : ['11', 'SWEDISH BLUE', 'MEDIUM - $34.88 - Limited Stock']}, { id : 3053690, values : ['012', '044', '003'], labels : ['12', 'NAVY', 'MEDIUM - $49.99 - Limited Stock']}, { id : 3714928, values : ['012', '120', '003'], labels : ['12', 'SWEDISH BLUE', 'MEDIUM - $34.88 - Limited Stock']}, { id : 3306332, values : ['013', '416', '003'], labels : ['13', 'CARIBBEAN SEA', 'MEDIUM - $49.99 - Limited Stock']}, { id : 3053691, values : ['013', '044', '003'], labels : ['13', 'NAVY', 'MEDIUM - $49.99 - Limited Stock']}, { id : 3053685, values : ['013', '609', '003'], labels : ['13', 'RAYA LILAC SACHET', 'MEDIUM - $34.88 - Limited Stock']}, { id : 3714929, values : ['013', '120', '003'], labels : ['13', 'SWEDISH BLUE', 'MEDIUM - $34.88 - Limited Stock']}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your json node should be enclosed in double quotes 
like

```
[{"id": 3306331}]
```

[Refer this site to learn json format](http://json.org/)

Comment: using quotes around `"3306331"` not necessary

Comment: @SandipPingle Thanks it worked! But it needs double qoutes for both keys and values.

Comment: if your values is numeric then quotes are optional, but for string values you need use quotes

Answer (score 0):

just use doublequotes aroun keys like this:

```
[{ "id" : 3306331, "values" : ["012", "416", "003"], ...
```

you needn't doublequotes or quotes around values if it is integer or float.

Comment: Two errors: Single quotes are not legal. And leading zeroes in numbers are not legal.

Comment: @gnasher729 you are right about single quotes -- they are not legal. Leading zeroes in strings are legal.

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine.

```
[{ "id" : 3306331, "values" : ["012", "416", "003"] }]
```

JSON nodes should be wrapped around double quotes. Also the values, if the number starts with a zero, wrap it around quotes and send it in form of string, as it expects a number to start with a non-zero digit.

```
[{ "id" : 3306331, "values" : [12, 416, 3] }]
```

These both will be valid JSON formats

Answer (score -1):

I am sorry. I have vallidated now..
try it

[{
    "id": "3306331",
    "values": [
        "012",
        "416",
        "003"
    ],
    "labels": [
        "12",
        "CARIBBEANSEA",
        "MEDIUM-$49.99-LimitedStock"
    ]
},{
    "id": "3306331",
    "values": [
        "012",
        "416",
        "003"
    ],
    "labels": [
        "12",
        "CARIBBEANSEA",
        "MEDIUM-$49.99-LimitedStock"
    ]
}
]

Comment: Did you validated with jsonlint? looks like again i am getting the same.